# Carga de archivos en 000webhost

Tags: servidor, host, carga

He desarrollado mi proyecto en local cuando intento subirlo al servidor en 000webhost, no puedo acceder a files.000webhost.com ni mediante WinScp.
En la primera opción el navegador me devuelve: "El servidor files.000webhost.com está tardando demasiado en responder". Y WinScp: "Tiempo expirado! (conexión de control) Error de conexión.".
Según he leído en algunos foros, he cambiado la contraseña, reiniciado el sitio, también he creado una cuenta nueva, y nada.

Definitivamente es el router, he probado mediante conexión desde el móvil y accedo sin problema.

¿Alguna solución?.

Ojalá puedan ayudarme.
Gracias

Edito:
Esto me devuelve el navegador cuando intento acceder a files.000webhost.com:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y eso el programa (winscp) que utilizo para subir los archivos mediante FTP:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He contactado con la compañía de internet y me preguntan si podría ser necesario abrir algún puerto. ¿Sabéis algo?.

Comment: Hola, Geline. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar la pregunta y añadir más información respecto a dónde intentas conectarte como por ejemplo si resuelve la IP correctamente?

Comment: Hola @AdrianFusco, soy nuevo en esto y desconozco que debo consultar/hacer. ¿Cuáles serían los pasos?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final, dejé pasar 3-4 días sin acceder y al intentarlo de nuevo ya funcionaba.

Answer (score 0):

000webhost es un proveedor de servicios de hosting gratuito, es decir, para subir tu página web.

Normalmente en los proveedores de hosting (hablo de los que son pago) te ofrecen al menos una de las dos siguientes alternativas para subir ficheros a tu hosting para montar tu web:

- **FTP**: File Transfer Protocol. Tiene básicamente la finalidad de transferir ficheros.
- **SSH**: Secure Shell. Su principal función es conectarte de forma remota a un servidor o dispositivo.

Entiendo que este proveedor aunque sea gratuito tiene alguna forma de subir los ficheros. De igual forma podrían tener un CPanel o un Panel donde podrás hacer la subida de estos.

Para conectarte por FTP necesitas usuario, contraseña (si no hay modo anónimo que en proveedores de hosting no lo hay) y servidor al cuál te vas a conectar. Aquí tienes un poco de información sobre la conexión FTP en este proveedor:

https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/where-can-i-find-my-ftp-information-11
https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/what-is-the-ftp-access-info-for-000webhost/

En teoría, en el área de cliente cuando entras a la web con tus credenciales te indican las credenciales de acceso por FTP.

Luego tienes:

- **SCP**: Secure Copy Protocol. Este hace uso de SSH para copiar los ficheros. En este caso necesitarías las credenciales de acceso por SSH. Hay algunos proveedores de hostings o dependiendo del tipo de servicio que no te ofrecen esta posibilidad.

Por lo que estuve investigando, lo más común que encontré es que en 000webhost.com hagas la conexión por FTP. En este caso lo mejor es que consigas estas credenciales accediendo a tu panel y luego con un programa como FileZilla (para mí la mejor opción) subas los ficheros.

Edito:

Como te comenté tienen un apartado en la web para subir los ficheros a tu web. Puedes acceder a la siguiente URL https://files.000webhost.com/. Tienes que subir los ficheros dentro de la carpeta public_html. El servicio web tiene este directorio asignado por así decirlo para que sea el principal para visualizar la web.

Sino puedes entrar paso a paso de la siguiente forma:

https://www.000webhost.com/ -> Sobre tu sitio web creado pasas el ratón y te aparecerá "Manage Website" -> Luego en el desplegable de la izquierda "Tools" -> Y en el subdesplegable "File Manager".

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Adrian muchas gracias por tu comentario, esos pasos los tengo claros. El problema viene cuando intento acceder mediante FTP o 'File Manager'.

Comment: ¿Te sucede al acceder vía web a través de [  https://files.000webhost.com/ ]? ¿Podrías adjuntar, por favor, una captura de este caso?

Comment: Si intento hacer ping desde administración del router a files.000webhost.com me da error pero no me proporciona más información. Por ello creo que es el router.

Comment: Perdón he visto tu comentario después. Ya he editado la pregunta.

Comment: Ah, no te preocupes. Sí, esto parece ya un problema de red. ¿Has intentado acceder desde otra red distinta? Por ejemplo, si el error te da intentando acceder a través del WiFi de tu red, ¿has intentado por ejemplo con una red móvil? Acceder desde el móvil, vamos. Inténtalo y nos comentas. Si puedes también sería bueno que abrieras CMD y ejecutaras el comando `tracert google.com` y `tracert files.000webhost.com`. Saludos.

Comment: Lo que comentas de abrir algún puerto no tiene que ser necesario. Si la web es http viaja por el puerto 80 la conexión y si es https por el puerto 443. Si puedes acceder a otras páginas http o https debería cargarte esta.

Comment: Respecto a lo que comentas de otra red, está en la pregunta. Accediendo mediante la red del móvil si que funciona.
Sobre los comandos CMD, el segundo al final devuelve 'Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.'.
Y sobre acceder a otras páginas nunca he tenido problemas.

Comment: Creo que deberías comentarlo con tu ISP o proveedor de servicios de internet. Si tienes contratado internet de forma normal, te han instalado el router y no han hecho nada adicional ni pasas por un proxy ni nada extraño debería funcionar. Creo que lo mejor es que lo comentes con ellos y les digas que no puedes hacer ni siquiera una traza de ruta para ver porque redes van pasando los paquetes (tracert). Si no tienes una configuración adicional en el ordenador, y si te conectas desde cualquier otro dispositivo al mismo WiFi (con un móvil ejemplo) sucede lo mismo deberías hablarlo con ellos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me pondré en contacto con ellos.

Comment: Nada, si contactas con ellos y te lo solucionan y ves que la información proporcionada te ha servido podrías marcar la respuesta como aceptada, en caso contrario podrías comentarnos más información en caso de que necesites más ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Me ha pasado muchas veces, busque en foros y la solución fue esperar unos dias, puede que tambien te pase al mes o a las semanas lo mismo, y tambien hay que esperar unos dias, supuestamente es por el mantenimiento que hacen ellos internamente

Comment: Considero que más allá si es de calidad o no el aporte esto parece más un comentario que de hecho el OP ya había puesto y no veo necesidad de duplicar, ahora un enlace que afirme lo que dices ayudaría